# Quitar Validación de Entidad en el cliente Swagger que migra por defecto despues de importar C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger

Creé un  `Web Api` en  `.Net Asp Net framework` (No es .NET Core) y luego agregué  `Swagger` para la documentación. Ahora mi entidad "Login" esta de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Login
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    public string NombreUsuario { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
    public string Contrasena { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Internamente, hago las validaciones con `Validator.TryValidateObject` para devolver el listado de errores y lo guardo en `List<ValidationResult>`. De esta manera y según mi lógica, el web api regresa todos los errores. De esta manera cualquier cliente puede mostrar los errores según crea conveniente. El json que devuelve el web api si se envían los campos en null es:

```
{
  "EstadoSolicitud": {
    "EstaCorrecto": false,
    "MensajeRespuesta": "El modelo ingresado no cumple la validación previa",
    "TipoNotificacionId": 4
  },
  "ListaErrorValidarModelo": [
    {
      "NombreCampo": "NombreUsuario",
      "MensajeError": "EL CAMPO USUARIO ES OBLIGATORIO."
    },
    {
      "NombreCampo": "Contrasena",
      "MensajeError": "EL CAMPO CONTRASEÑA ES OBLIGATORIO."
    }
  ]
}
```

Note que ya regreso el error y el atributo al que se afecta para mejorar su claridad.

Ahora he creado un cliente para consumir mi API en c# importando swagger con la herramienta que da visual studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me ha importado correctamente las entidades y las configuraciones de mi web api, pero tengo el problema que dentro del código autogenerado, la librerìa swagger hacer otra validación como se ve a continuación:

```
            if (login == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.CannotBeNull, "login");
            }
            if (login != null)
            {
                login.Validate();
            }
```

Esta validación no me sirve, pues todo el trabajo de validar la entidad ya lo hago en el web api. No encuentro documentación de como deshabilitar dicha validación para que no migre desde swagger.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, posiblemente no estés configurando Swagger en tu Web API de manera correcta. Te recomiendo leas detenidamente este artículo [Swagger - Documentando un Web API 2 de ASP.NET Framework](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/7/16/swagger-documentando-un-web-api-2-de-aspnet-framework)

Comment: Hola, puede dar una muestra de como debe estar configurado para estos casos?